# Shopware 6 : How to make work my own Request in Postman using Admin API

Tags: api, postman, shopware, shopware6

I have created my own Request API ( POST : {{baseUrl}}/products/create ). This API is used to create many products and returns only the total number of existing products in Shopware. I want to execute my request in postman, but I can not. There is a way to make work the request in Postman ?

ApiController.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace TestApi\Controller\Api;

use Shopware\Core\Framework\Context;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Routing\Annotation\RouteScope;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

/**
 * @RouteScope(scopes={"api"})
 */
class ApiController extends AbstractController
{
    protected EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }
    /**
     * @Route("/products/create", name="api.product.create", methods={"POST"})
     */
    public function createProducts(Context $context): JsonResponse
    {
        $this->productRepository->create([
            [
                'name' => 'Product 1',
                'productNumber' => 'SW1231',
                'stock' => 10,
                'taxId' => 'bc3f1ba6f75749c79b5b4a9d673cf9d4',
                'price' => [['currencyId' => Defaults::CURRENCY, 'gross' => 50, 'net' => 25, 'linked' => false]],
            ],[
                'name' => 'Product 2',
                'productNumber' => 'SW1232',
                'stock' => 10,
                'taxId' => 'bc3f1ba6f75749c79b5b4a9d673cf9d4',
                'price' => [['currencyId' => Defaults::CURRENCY, 'gross' => 50, 'net' => 25, 'linked' => false]],
            ]
        ], $context);

        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $products = $this->productRepository->search($criteria, $context);

        return new JsonResponse($products->count());
    }
}
```

Postman :

[image: below is the response]

For information I have provided the Authorization header  in the request.

Comment: What value is the {{ baseUrl }}?

Comment: {{baseUrl}} is a variable that points to the Shopware domain (ex : https://shop-example.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your issue lies inside your controller, you use the `api` route scope, which means that the `api` authentication mechanism should be used. But all routes with the `api` route scope need to start with the `/api` prefix in the path.

Routes without a `/api` or `/store-api` prefix are assumed to be storefront requests with the storefront authorization. You should also get an error because of the mismatch of route scope and actual api path, but probably the CSRF error is thrown before that is validated.

To fix your code use `/api/products/create` as the path for your custom controller action and also use the `/api` prefix in postman to access your route.

Comment: I have fixed the route to `@Route("/api/products/create", name="api.product.create", methods={"POST"})` and I have tested this request in postman  `https://shop-example.com/api/products/create` but I get the following error again : `"No route found for \"POST https://shop-example.com/api/products/create\"`

Comment: Please check that your plugin with that controller is installed and active and clear the cache after changing the route name, as symfony heavily caches all available routes in order match the routes in a performant way

Comment: Additionally please make sure that you configured the routes.xml correctly so that symfony actually looks into you controller when it searches for route annotations, refer to the docs here: https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-controller#routes.xml-example

Answer (score 2):

You're making a request against the storefront, not an api endpoint. The CSRF protection only comes into play in the storefront. Is your `baseUrl` missing the `/api` prefix? The value should be like `http://localhost/api`.

Comment: I have made some changes like `@Route("/api/products/create", name="api.product.create", methods={"POST"})` . I have tested the request in Postman und I get this error : `No route found for \"POST https://shop-example.com/api/products/create\`